# ansible: How to avoid warnings

Tags: python, python3, monitoring, cluster, ansible

I am using ansible for monitoring my home computing net, which consists several Linux machines (x64 and Raspberries).
How can I avoid warnings from every Raspberry client?

> [WARNING]: Platform linux on host raspi6.local is using the discovered
> Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of
> another Python interpreter could change this. See
> https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html
> for more information. raspi6.local | CHANGED | rc=0 >>  16:11:44 up
> 21:02,  3 users,  load average: 4,04, 4,01, 4,00

Answer (score 22):

In the ansible config file on your ansible controlled host... add the following line

```
vim ~/.ansible.cfg
```

```
[defaults]
interpreter_python=auto_silent
```